# SQL Server and DateTime fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got this strange problem which I'm sure is well known - When I insert a date like '20/08/2010' I mean it to be as 'dd/mm/yyyy' where MSSQL expects it to be 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

How can it be changed for MSSQL to expect 'dd/mm/yyyy' as the field format.

Thanks!

Comment: not enough details, are you inserting from a script, a bound variable, etc...

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Control to insert using an INSERT statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Setting a standard DateFormat for SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/setting-a-standard-dateformat-for-sql-se) to see a couple of ways. `SET DATEFORMAT MDY` is one way

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28SQL.80%29.aspx for the (not-so-intuitive) set of date format codes.

(Sounds like you want to CONVERT(DATETIME, '20/08/2010', 103) )

Comment: I really do want this CONVERT - but BEFORE I insert it.

Comment: So...INSERT INTO t1 (date_col) VALUES(CONVERT(DATETIME, '20/08/2010', 103) )?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to set the format of field using str_to_date function

insert into   values (str_to_date('08/09/2010', '%d/%m/%Y'))